# In python, create md5 hash from the last 4KB of a file

Tags: python, hash

In python, given a really large file (~700MB), how can I create an md5 hash only from the last 4096kb of that file?

Comment: I would read this: http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/37186-md5-large-files It should help you

Comment: No problem, I'll admit I was intrigued by your post, I had never considered only md5'ing part of a file but from what I read in the thread I read/am reading it can be dangerous to md5 the first (or for that matter the last) part of the file as some files will have similar "headers" and "footers". I am sure that it depends on what type of file you are working with in regards to if a first X or last X number of bits are usually unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`seek`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file.seek) to move the file pointer to the end of the file, and [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html) for MD5:

```
import hashlib
with open('really-large-file', 'rb') as f:
    f.seek(- 4096 * 1024, 2)
    print (hashlib.md5(f.read()).hexdigest())
```

Comment: Just curious, why was this a bad question?

Comment: @ensnare I have no idea. You switched around KB and KiB (4096000 B would be a weird size, so I assumed KiB). Also, a hashsum over only part of a file may be a bad idea, since files can have known footers. For example, if the same file occurs at the end of two tarballs, you may get the same hash despite the tarballs being different.